# Laravel 5.6 - DB select Call to a member function join() on array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have following query:

```php
$clinics =  \DB::select('SELECT * FROM
(SELECT *,
 (100 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(lat)) *
 cos(radians(lng) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
 sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(lat))))
 AS distance
 FROM clinics) AS distances
 WHERE distance < 100
 ORDER BY distance')
 ->join('countries', 'clinics.country_id', '=', 'countries.id');
```

When I run it I am getting following error:

```php
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Call to a member function join() on array
```

Is it possible to perform **JOIN** with this query? 
I tried adding **JOIN** in the select query, but I am getting an error:

```php
Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'clinics.country_id' in 'on clause' (SQL: SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, (100 * acos(cos(radians(43.1557012)) * cos(radians(lat)) * cos(radians(lng) - radians(22.5856811)) + sin(radians(43.1557012)) * sin(radians(lat)))) AS distance FROM clinics) AS distances JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id WHERE distance < 100 ORDER BY distance)
```

The query in question:

```php
$clinics =  \DB::select('SELECT * FROM
    (SELECT *,
     (100 * acos(cos(radians(' . $lat . ')) * cos(radians(lat)) *
     cos(radians(lng) - radians(' . $lng . ')) +
     sin(radians(' . $lat . ')) * sin(radians(lat))))
     AS distance
     FROM clinics) AS distances
     JOIN countries ON countries.id = clinics.country_id
     WHERE distance < 100
     ORDER BY distance');
```

Comment: try replacing your clinics with distances,plus why are you using db raw,dont you use laravel's eloquent?Its much easier

Comment: It doesn't work because `DB::select()` already executes the query. What's your Laravel version?

Comment: Why do you want to extract the join from your raw query? In my opinion this makes only sense if you try to transform the whole query into Laravel query builder notation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, the sub query is not necessary and you can transform the query into Laravel notation like so:

```
$clinics = Clinic::join('countries', 'countries.id', '=', 'clinics.country_id')
    ->selectRaw('clinics.*, countries.*, (
        100 * acos(
            cos(radians(?)) *
            cos(radians(lat)) *
            cos(radians(lng) - radians(?)) +
            sin(radians(?)) * sin(radians(lat))
        )
    ) as distance', [$lat, $lng, $lat])
    ->having('distance', '<', 100)
    ->orderBy('distance')
    ->get();
```

You might want to explicitely list which columns you want to select of the `countries` table because with `countries.*` you will override for example the `id` column of your `clinics` table. I added `countries.*` because I guess this is what you wanted to do after joining the tables.